# Winston logger - Querying all logs?

Tags: node.js, winston

I noticed winston by default queries only 10 logs. Is there any way to get all the logs other than specifying a huge number as limit?
I have tried specifying `0` and `-1` but it didn't work :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid not. As you can see in [source code](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/lib/winston/transports/transport.js):

> `L68` options.rows = options.rows || options.limit || 10;

there is no way to fetch all entries unless you change source code.

Answer (score 0):

Just set to **limit** property value **Infinity**.

More details about infinity value [can be found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity).